# Intercepting mouse software calls to usb mouse

Tags: windows, usb, mouse, macros

I'm running win10 x64. I have a Pictek PC231A gaming mouse, which comes with macro buttons and a software to map buttons to keys/macros (among other things). I want to preface this by saying that I have tried 8 other gaming mice before and spent hours looking online for the perfect fit, and this is the only one I found. So changing mice is not an option.

The mouse is able to switch between 2 modes, where each mode is a user-made mapping of keys/macro:
[image]

The very frustrating thing is that the developers seem to have forgotten to add a bindable command to alternate between these modes! Having experience with other mice, I can say this is a first. To switch modes, I have to open the software and click the mode I want to switch to, which is very inconvenient as I usually do that all the time.

I'd like to hack my way out of this by reproducing whatever signal is sent to the mouse programmatically. If that is possible, I first need to figure out what signal the software sends to the mouse to switch modes. Is that possible?

Comment: I'd almost guarantee the mode isn't switched in the mouse, but in the driver/control panel. The mouse just sends button-presses, the driver interprets according to which map is active.

Comment: Would it be possible to find a way to programmatically control the software to make it change modes then?

Comment: potentially, but idk Windows well enough. On mac, Similar mice can be controlled by 3rd party drivers which can have different settings per app [though still not 2 sets of settings in any one app].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've probably figured this out already, but you can press the plus and minus keys on the top at the same time for a few seconds and it switches mode, it should flash when you have pressed it long enough . hope this helps.

Comment: I hadn't! Thank you so much.